# How to stop long text in textview overlapping an image on left constraint

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a image and a textview next to it in a constraint layout, textview has a really long text and I want fit the text within the text view and not overlap  on the image

this is what I have tried

[image]

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tariffTileHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/tariffIconIV"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_electricity_circle_logo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tariffDescTV"
            style="@style/Text.Large.Bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tariffIconIV"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is a very long name to be sue it fits no matter how long it is" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it looks

could you suggest what I am missing here please

thanks for your suggestions
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Set  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and  `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"`of textView (tariffDescTV) and width of parent container as `match_parent`.

### Output

(I have used image of cross for example)

- Output when text is long

[image: Output when text is long]

- Output when text is short
  [image: Output when text is short]

### Code For the Same

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tariffTileHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/tariffIconIV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cross"
    android:tint="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tariffDescTV"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tariffDescTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="3"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tariffIconIV"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="This is a short message" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, one issue I have is the text is dynamic so sometimes it will be long sometimes it will be short, so when the text is smaller it should be in the centre aligned, how can i achieve that please

Comment: @BRDroid set attribute `textAlignment = center` in  textview

Comment: I basically want the image and the text to be in the centre when text is small and when the text is bigger, expand,
if I apply textAlignment to center, text will be in centre and the image to the left. but i want text and image to be next to each other in centre

Comment: @BRDroid I have updated the code according to your requirements. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer as it may help someone in future.

Comment: I did that already :)

Comment: @BRDroid Thanks man ;)

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to set up the text in the layout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/tariffIconIV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tariffDescTV"
        style="@style/Text.Large.Bold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tariffIconIV"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is a very long name to be sue it fits no matter how long it is" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the desired output.

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, one issue I have is the text is dynamic so sometimes it will be long sometimes it will be short, so when the text is smaller it should be in the centre aligned, how can i achieve that please

Comment: you can give the attribute textalignment  to center and the width is 0dp so it will be adjusted automatically

Comment: I basically want the image and the text to be in the centre when text is small and when the text is bigger, expand,
if I apply textAlignment to center, text will be in centre and the image to the left. but i want text and image to be next to each other in centre